# Import cyrillic csv-file to Vertica via TOAD

Tags: toad, vertica

I am struggling to import csv-file with cyrillic symbols to a table at Hp Vertica and every time I get the error

```
[Vertica][ODBC] (10170) String data right truncation on data from data source: String data is too big for the driver's data buffer
```

I tried to import utf8-saved .csv file and cp1251-saved .csv file, but the error is still there.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've never seen that error.  Is your delimiter set properly to match the csv?   How about the end of record? How long is each row? Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The "String data right truncation" error can have two causes:

1. Target column is not big enough. Remember: (a) Vertica uses a **byte-oriented length semantic** for CHAR/VARCHAR and (b) it wants UTF-8 in input. So, for example, if you want to store the Euro sign (one, single, character) the target column should be - at least - CHAR(3) because the Euro sign requires three bytes when encoded UTF-8
2. The other possibility is that your ODBC loader does not allocate enough memory to store your string and/or does not understand field separators

Forget about CP-1251. Vertica wants UTF-8 in input.

Comment: But i tried to save csv-file in UTF8 and got the same error. Interesting that I can easily work with my file in TOAD as a connection but I cant import it to a table.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example (including table defilintion and one row o data).?